# How to fix an element that isn't responding to it's javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener

```js
function appear() {
 document.querySelector(".modal-bg").style.display = 'flex';
 document.querySelector(".modal-bg2").style.display = 'flex';
}
document.querySelector(".close").addEventListener("click", function() {
 document.querySelector(".modal-bg").style.display = 'none';
 document.querySelector(".modal-bg2").style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
body {
 background-image:url("https://i.ibb.co/KqdJ9Dm/218752.jpg");
 background-size:cover;
}
#fc {
 color:white;
 font-weight:bold;
 height:50px;
 width:90px;
 background-image:linear-gradient(#DA4453, #89216B);
 position:relative;
 left:605px;
 top:65px;
}
.modal-bg,.modal-bg2 {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  display:none;
  
}
.modal-content,.modal-content2 {
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
  border-radius:10px;
  position:relative;
  background-color:white;
  top:25px;
}
.modal-bg2 {
 left:600px;
 
 
}
.modal-bg {
 right:315px;
 
 
}
#answer {
 width:140px;
 height:60px;
 position:relative;
 left:185px;
 border-top:none;
 border-left:none;
 border-right:none;
 border-bottom:2px solid black;
 outline:none;
 font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;

}

.close {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 right:14px;
 font-size:32px;
 transform:rotate(45deg);

}
#s {
 position:absolute;
 top:200px;
 left:225px;
 background-image:linear-gradient(#DA4453, #89216B);
 color:white;
 font-weight:bold;
}
#title {
 border-bottom:2px solid black;
 outline:none;
 border-top:none;
 border-left:none;
 border-right:none;
 font-size:25px;
 font-weight:bold;
 position:relative;
 left:65px;
 top:95px;
 
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   text-align: center;
}
button {
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Flash Card Pro</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<h1 align = "center">Flash Card Pro  </h1>
<button id = "fc" onclick = appear();>ADD A FLASH CARD</button>
<div class = "modal-bg">
<div class = "modal-content">
<input type = "text" placeholder="TYPE YOUR QUESTION" id="title" required>
<div class = "close">+</div>
</div>
<div class = "modal-bg2">
<div class = "modal-content2">
<h2 align = "center">TYPE YOUR ANSWER</h2>
<textarea name="answer" cols="4" rows="2" placeholder="TYPE YOUR ANSWER" id = "answer"></textarea>
<input type = "submit" id = "s"  onclick = close()>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a div element which has a class of close, and it's not responding correctly to my javascript. I used the addEventListener click to execute a function which makes the bgmodal and bgmodal2 divs display none. Every time I click on the element close it doesn't do anything it's supposed to do and there are no errors. I don't think there's a problem with the elements because I tested it on other elements too.

I've tried using the addEventListener part of the code on the div called s. I've also tried doing the function differently like document.querySelector(close).onclick = function() and just function close() and then calling it with onclick in the Html, it works on StackOverflow and I'm using google chrome why isn't working there?

Comment: .modal-bg2 is overlapping the button, suggest having a rejig of your css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an element overlap problem. It's not possible to click the `.close` element because there's another element sat on top of it (`.modal-bg2`).

You've set the close element to position absolute. Give it a z-index value to make sure it's on top.

```
.close {
    . . .
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: I didn't want to bloat the answer with this unrelated remark so I've opted to post it as a comment instead. There's a few recommendations I could give at this point but the one that stands out to me the most is that "close" should be a button, not a div.

Comment: alternatively the OP could also add a role of button and tabindex=0